# How do you get initial and trailing metadata from an async python gRPC client?

Tags: python, api, asynchronous, metadata, grpc

I'm trying to write a Python async gRPC client and server but I can't figure out how to get the initial and trailing metadata from a request.

It looks like from the python gRPC documentation, the sync client's `UnaryUnaryMultiCallable` has a [future](https://grpc.github.io/grpc/python/grpc.html#grpc.UnaryUnaryMultiCallable.future) and a [with_call](https://grpc.github.io/grpc/python/grpc.html#grpc.UnaryUnaryMultiCallable.with_call) method for getting the initial and trailing metadata, respectively.

There's also [this example](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/examples/python/metadata/metadata_client.py#L31) in the GitHub repo of accessing the trailing metadata.

But the async version of the `UnaryUnaryMultiCallable` doesn't have similar methods, only `__call__` which only returns the (awaitable) response.

Is there a different way to access initial and trailing metadata from an async client?

Comment: When you say async, do you mean `asyncio`? As in [this class](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/70b26a1c7c372c67703c526fe11f9b1516aa8ab8/src/python/grpcio/grpc/aio/_channel.py#L116)? I ask because gRPC Python supports three different kinds of asynchronous exectuion.

Also, are you asking about getting the metadata from a request on the _client side_? Because if so, this isn't actually supported in the sync stack. Note that these methods on [grpc.Call](https://grpc.github.io/grpc/python/grpc.html#grpc.Call.details) get the metadata sent by the _server_.

What is your use case here?

Answer (score 0):

`UnaryUnaryMultiCallable` return `_base_call.UnaryUnaryCall`
if you await it, `def __await__(self) -> Awaitable[ResponseType]:`, it will return `ResponseType`

if you want to get meta_data, you should not await `_base_call.UnaryUnaryCall`

You can check `grpc.aio.Call`

You should do something like this in client :

```
async def run() -> None:
    async with grpc.aio.insecure_channel(target="localhost:50051") as channel:
        stub = helloworld_pb2_grpc.GreeterStub(channel)

        try:
            r_header = (
                ("mesasge", "1010"),
                ("error", "No Error"),
            )

            call = stub.SayHello(
                helloworld_pb2.HelloRequest(name="hello"),
                timeout=10,
                metadata=r_header,
            )
            response = await call

            print("Client received: " + response.message)

            print(await call.code())
            print(await call.details())
            print(await call.initial_metadata())
            print(await call.trailing_metadata())

        except grpc.aio._call.AioRpcError as e:
            print(e.code())
            print(e.details())
            print(e.initial_metadata())
            print(e.trailing_metadata())
```